# IllegalStateException when removing an object from a Collection

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am iterating through an arrayList and removing items that apply to certain criteria.

```
public static ArrayList<String> filteredArrayList(HashMap<String, Boolean> filters){

    ArrayList<String> filteredArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    filteredArrayList = fullList();

    Iterator<String> i = filteredArrayList.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        String s = i.next();

        if(!(filters.get("sometextStatus")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("sometext".trim().toLowerCase()))){
                i.remove();
        }
        if(!(filters.get("120Status")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("120".trim().toLowerCase()))){
                i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does first statement work:

```
if(!(filters.get("sometextStatus")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("sometext".trim().toLowerCase()))){
    i.remove();
}
```

But the second one fails?

```
if(!(filters.get("120Status")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("120".trim().toLowerCase()))){
    i.remove();
}
```

I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException

for the second one.

Comment: what are "s" and "i" ? I would help to understand, to know the type for example, you can show the loop maybe (without useless lines)

Comment: I think there is something missing in the code you provided from counting the brackets.

Comment: To get proper answer to your question post [mcve].

Comment: To update your question use [edit] option.

Comment: we need to see your code, as well contains return boolean and there is no sense using trim on a string you know have no spaces in.

Comment: Beneath the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException` are a series of lines starting with `at` or `Caused by:`.  Those lines are called a stack trace, and they are crucial information.  They tell you (and us) exactly where the problem occurred.  Please edit your question and copy and paste those lines into it.

Comment: Sorry guys, updated with everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<String> filteredArrayList(HashMap<String, Boolean> filters){

    ArrayList<String> filteredArrayList = fullList(); //Note, that fullList method already creates and returns array, so you don't need to create it before calling this method.

    Iterator<String> i = filteredArrayList.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        String s = i.next();

        if(!(filters.get("sometextStatus")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("sometext".trim().toLowerCase()))){
                i.remove();
                continue; //We removed current element, so next if check might potentially removed already removed element!
        }

        if(!(filters.get("120Status")) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("120".trim().toLowerCase()))){
                i.remove();
                continue; //Maybe a programmer will decide to copy-paste if checks, so it is safer to do so with continue.
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

After debugging, I found

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ca.training.jdk.loops.Main2.filteredArrayList(Main2.java:34)
    at com.ca.training.jdk.loops.Main2.main(Main2.java:14)
```

The problem is that if

```
 filters.get("120Status")
```

returns **NULL**, which is possible!?. So add a null check

```
Boolean status1 = filters.get("sometextStatus");
if((status1 != null && status1) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("sometext".trim().toLowerCase()))) {
    i.remove();
}
```

The keyword `continue` makes the program continue the loop with new loop parameter. So when first `if` statement is true, we do not go to the second `if` check, but continue the loop execution with the next `i` value.

**Advice**

Use base classes or interfaces instead of child classes wherever it is possible.

```
  public static ArrayList<String> filteredArrayList(Map<String, Boolean> filters){ //Note, map

  List<String> filteredArrayList = fullList(); //Note, list.
```

Comment: also we can use `else if`

Comment: I agree, in the **remove** case we can. What if instead of *remove* the OP wants to put them into another collection? Then it is better to use if without else. Again, I agree, in this case, **else if** is fine!

Comment: I am still getting the error. Can you explain what the function of continue is here? Edit: nevermind, it does work with continue. Does this just iterate the loop or something?

Comment: @ConfidentKeyboard  I am still getting the error. Runtime or compile error?

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Is there any advantage in using continue rather than else if statements?

Comment: @ConfidentKeyboard I updated my post. You can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @YanKhonski Thank you for the update! I didn't think of that!

Comment: @YanKhonski I tried adding your null check, but I am getting this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '!='
  first type:  boolean
  second type: <nulltype>

Comment: @YanKhonsk It works if I just use the .get(), without creating a new boolean: filters.get("1Status") != null && filters.get("1Status")

Comment: `if((status1 != null && status1) && (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains("sometext".trim().toLowerCase()))) {`

This is if check. Why do you use **!**. I checked my code, and it works. It removes strings that match the criteria.

Comment: @YanKhonski I had boolean instead of Boolean...whoops.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first `i.remove()` did already remove the element. When the second check also matches, the second `i.remove()` is not possible anymore and instead an Exception is thrown. Use `continue;` whenever you did call `i.remove()`.

`continue` will jump to the next element of your loop.

But this would be much easier to find out if you would post the exact line of code where the Exception occured.

Comment: The exact line of code is: i.remove(); on the second if statement.

Comment: Ok, so then you have to call "continue" after the i.remove() or use else if instead of the second if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Java8 maybe this could help.

You don't need to `trim()` the item as we check the content, not an exact match.

You also don't need to `lowerCase()` it if you match the number.

Simple lambda to remove the items:

```
filteredArrayList.removeIf(s ->
                s.contains("123")
             || s.toLowerCase().contains("asd".toLowerCase())
             || s.toLowerCase().contains("something else".toLowerCase())
             || s.toLowerCase().contains("something else".toLowerCase())
        );
```

`s` is the item in the list you can call it as you want- it's an iterator's item yes.

Comment: Hmm, could this be used multiple times, say to remove items with different strings contained in them? Also, what is s in this context? Does this still need an iterator?

Comment: Thanks! Which way is better? Are there any advantages to this method?

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance, its cleaner and more modern I presume, easier to read and take less space, less confusion. Probably underneath it does something similar to yours.

Comment: I think the original method may be better for my application. I would like to split the if statements into sections, since there will be a lot of filtering, and possibly many conditions on the filtering. Thanks though, I didn't know about .removeIf

Comment: your choice ;) its just an option, I would prefer to use few lambdas even, than to have a huge method with a hundred of if statements. I have just proposed the alternative solution.

Comment: What is a lambda?